# Did I find a mistake in a classic proof? If not, could someone help me understand?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, least-common-multiple

I am working through Denis Hanson's [proof](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267137759_On_the_product_of_the_primes) that LCM$(1,2,3,\dots,n) < 3^n$

To be clear, the mistake is minor and does not affect the result achieved.  Still, I was surprised.

Here's what I believe is wrong (on page 36):

> Observe that
>   $$\frac{a_1-1}{a_1} + \frac{a_2-1}{a_2} + \dots + \frac{a_k-1}{a_k} = \left(1 - \frac{1}{a_1}\right) + \dots + \left(1 - \frac{1}{a_k}\right)$$
>   $$ = k - 1 + \frac{1}{a_{k+1}+1}$$

where $a_i$ is defined as:

- $a_1 = 2$
- $a_{n+1} = a_1 a_2 \dots a_n + 1$

I believe that the corrected version should read:

> $$= k - 1 + \frac{1}{a_{k+1} - 1}$$

Here is my reasoning:

- It is true for $k=1$ since $\frac{a_1 -1 }{a_1} = \frac{2-1}{2} = (1 - 1) + \frac{1}{3 - 1} = (1 - 1) + \frac{1}{a_2 - 1}$
- Assume that my hypothesis is true up to some $k \ge 1$
  $$\frac{a_1 - 1}{a_1} + \dots + \frac{a_{k} - 1}{a_k} = k - 1 + \frac{1}{a_{k+1}-1}$$
- $\frac{a_1 - 1}{a_1} + \dots + \frac{a_{k+1} - 1}{a_{k+1}} = (k - 1 + \frac{1}{a_{k+1}-1}) + 1 - \frac{1}{a_{k+1}}=$
  $(k+1) - 1 + \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k+1}(a_{k+1}-1)} - \frac{a_{k+1}-1}{a_{k+1}(a_{k+1}-1)} = (k+1) - 1 + \frac{1}{a_{k+1}^2 - a_{k+1}} =$ 
  $(k+1) - 1 + \frac{1}{a_{k+2}-1}$

Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are right. (You have a typo in the last bullet point. $(a_{k+1}-1)/a_k$ should be $(a_{k+1}-1)/a_{k+1}$).

Comment: Thanks!  I fixed the typo.  I appreciate all your help!