# Not clear in one step in the inequality for the proof LCM$(1,2,\dots,n) < 3^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-function, proof-explanation, least-common-multiple

I believe that I am following Hanson's [proof](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267137759_On_the_product_of_the_primes) up until this point (page 36):

> $$C(n) < \dfrac{(en)^{k-1+1/(a_{k+1}+1)}w^n}{(a_1)^{(a_1-1)/a_1}(a_2)^{(a_2-1)/a_2}\dots(a_m)^{(a_k-1)/a_k}}$$

where $e$ is [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), $a_1=2$, $a_{i+1} = a_1 a_2 \dots a_i + 1$ so that:

- $a_2 = 3$
- $a_3 = 7$

$k$ is the value where $a_k \le n < a_{k+1}$

$w^n$ is not important for my question but it is defined as $w = a_1^{1/a_1}a_2^{1/a_2}\dots$

I am unclear at this step where:

> $$C(n) < \dfrac{(en)^{k-1+1/(a_{k+1}+1)}w^n}{(a_1)^{(a_1-1)/a_1}(a_2)^{(a_2-1)/a_2}\dots(a_m)^{(a_k-1)/a_k}}< e^{k - 3/2}n^{k - 3/2}w^n$$

where $k > 2$ since $n < a_1 a_2 \dots a_k$

Here's what I understand:

- Since each $a_i > 1$, I am clear why:

> $$\dfrac{(en)^{k-1+1/(a_{k+1}+1)}w^n}{(a_1)^{(a_1-1)/a_1}(a_2)^{(a_2-1)/a_2}\dots(a_m)^{(a_k-1)/a_k}}< e^{k - 1 + 1/(a_{k+1}+1)}n^{k - 1 + 1/(a_{k+1}+1)}w^n$$

- If he meant to use $k - \frac{3}{4}$, then I would be clear since:

> $$(en)^{k-1+1/(a_{k+1}+1)}w^n < e^{k - 3/4}n^{k - 3/4}w^n$$

- If $k - \frac{3}{2}$ is correct, then I would appreciate help in understanding how this follows.

It is not obvious to me that this is true or why it is true.

Comment: @Clayton, I explored that direction but couldn't see how $a_i$ would relate to $(en)$.  I think that you are right that this is where the answer should be.  If I figure it out, I will update my question to show what I came up with.

Comment: Only a partial answer: the denominator simplifies to $(a_1\cdots a_k)(a_1^{-1/a_1}\cdots a_k^{-1/a_k})$. Using that $n\leq a_1\cdots a_k$ (this is by hypothesis), we can say that $(\text{right-hand side})\leq\frac{1}{n(a_1^{-1/a_1}\cdots a_k^{-1/a_k})}$. Now part of the problem that remains is the product of $a_i^{1/a_i}$ tends to a limit that is greater than $e$. With a negative exponent (in the denominator), this seems to imply that the exponent of $e$ should increase by a quantity of at least $1$.

Comment: @Clayton, I think that this suggests that it may be a mistake.  Hanson shows that $a_1 a_2 \dots a_k > n$ and $a_1^{1/a_1}a_2^{1/a_2}\dots < 2.952$ so that the denominator is roughly $n/2.952$ which is smaller than $n/e$.

Comment: Larry, that was precisely my point. @mathlove caught the mistake, though! This makes it all alright :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950228/did-i-find-a-mistake-in-a-classic-proof-if-not-could-someone-help-me-understan), I think (2.6) should be
$$C(n) < \dfrac{(en)^{k-1+1/(a_{k+1}\color{red}{-}1)}w^n}{a_1^{(a_1-1)/a_1}a_2^{(a_2-1)/a_2}\dots a_k^{(a_k-1)/a_k}}\lt  e^{k - 3/2}n^{k - 3/2}w^n$$
(see the minus sign in red in the numerator)

To prove 
$$\dfrac{(en)^{k-1+1/(a_{k+1}-1)}w^n}{a_1^{(a_1-1)/a_1}a_2^{(a_2-1)/a_2}\dots a_k^{(a_k-1)/a_k}}\lt  e^{k - 3/2}n^{k - 3/2}w^n\tag1$$
it is sufficient to prove
$$(en)^{k-1+1/(a_{k+1}-1)-(k-3/2)}\lt  a_1^{(a_1-1)/a_1}a_2^{(a_2-1)/a_2}\dots a_k^{(a_k-1)/a_k},$$
i.e.
$$(en)^{1/2+1/(a_{k+1}-1)}\lt  a_1^{(a_1-1)/a_1}a_2^{(a_2-1)/a_2}\dots a_k^{(a_k-1)/a_k}$$
Since $n\le a_1a_2\cdots a_k$, it is sufficient to prove
$$(ea_1a_2\cdots a_k)^{1/2+1/(a_{k+1}-1)}\lt  a_1^{(a_1-1)/a_1}a_2^{(a_2-1)/a_2}\dots a_k^{(a_k-1)/a_k},$$
i.e.
$$e^{1/2+1/(a_{k+1}-1)}\lt a_1^{1/2-1/a_1-1/(a_{k+1}-1)}a_2^{1/2-1/a_2-1/(a_{k+1}-1)}\cdots a_k^{1/2-1/a_k-1/(a_{k+1}-1)},$$
i.e.
$$e^{1/2+1/(a_{k+1}-1)}2^{1/(a_{k+1}-1)}\lt a_2^{1/2-1/a_2-1/(a_{k+1}-1)}\cdots a_k^{1/2-1/a_k-1/(a_{k+1}-1)}$$
Since $a_i^{1/2-1/a_i-1/(a_{k+1}-1)}\gt 1$ for $2\le i\le k-1$,
It is sufficient to prove 
$$e^{1/2+1/(a_{k+1}-1)}2^{1/(a_{k+1}-1)}\lt a_k^{1/2-1/a_k-1/(a_{k+1}-1)}\tag2$$
for $k\ge 3$.

Note here that seeing $(2)$ as an inequality on $k$, we see that the LHS of $(2)$ is decreasing and that the RHS of $(2)$ is increasing, so it is sufficient to prove $(2)$ for $k=3$, which is equivalent to
$$2e^{22}\lt 7^{14}$$
which is indeed true.

Therefore, $(1)$ is true.

Comment: Wow.  Great job.  I was convinced that Hanson had made another mistake.  I am very glad to hear that I was wrong.